# Could not find configuration node: wffmRepository

Tags: .net, sitecore, sitecore7.2, web-forms-for-marketers

I'm working with Sitecore 7.2 and WFFM 2.4 and I am getting a strange error on one of our servers whenever I attempt to add an MVC form to a page stating "Could not find configuration node: wffmRepository". I've looked high and low for any reference to wffmRepository but have come up empty. Has anyone encountered an error like this before? I'm at a loss as to where to look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `wffmRepository` is defined in the `Sitecore.MvcForms.config` which located in the config directory `/App_Config/Include` and included as part of the default WFFM installation package.

Make sure the file is present, enabled and the config node is defined. Also check you do not have any config patch files which delete the node. Use `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` to ensure it is defined.

For reference, the default defintion of this node is:

```
<wffmRepository type="Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Services.FormRepository,Sitecore.Forms.Mvc" singleInstance="false">
  <param name="renderingContext" ref="wffmRenderingContext" />
</wffmRepository>
```